# How to add text chat to opentok video chat

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, tokbox

I am working on an IOS application(SWIFT) in which i have used tokbox sdk for adding video chat into ios app.
now i want to add text chat option during video call!

Can anyone guide how to add text chat option during video call in iOS app using tokbox sdk?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `signal` for chat and sending data between clients connected to an OpenTok session.

Here is the reference like : https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/signaling/ios-swift/

In doc have full information.
Here is the sample code.

```
import OpenTok

enum TokBoxSignalType: String {
    case message = "message"
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var openTokSession: OTSession?
    
    @IBAction func onSendMessage(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //send message to OTSignal
        var error: OTError?
        defer {
            self.handleOTError(error)
        }
        openTokSession?.signal(withType: TokBoxSignalType.message.rawValue, string: "send_chat_message", connection: nil, error: &error)
    }
    
    
    //Handle OpenTok errors
    private func handleOTError(_ error: OTError?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("There is an error : ", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
}


//MARK : Signal Methods
extension ViewController {
    func session(_ session: OTSession, receivedSignalType type: String?, from connection: OTConnection?, with string: String?) {
        guard let typeEnum = TokBoxSignalType(rawValue: type ?? "") else {
            return
        }
        
        switch typeEnum {
        case .message:
            print(string)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the reference link! Is there any sample project (ios swift) github that uses signal for text chat during video call ?

Comment: Yes, I checked before but now I can't find the link.

Comment: We have an example project but it is in objc. But works just the same https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples/tree/main/Signaling

Comment: @MoulaliPinjari here I attached the sample code demo.

Comment: @abdulajet, im trying to implement text chat during video call.i have some doubts regarding implementation of text chat.
should i build my own user interface for text chat ?
can u share if u have any working sample of implementing text chat in ios app (swift)

Comment: My above comment has a sample in objc, but the API and principals are the same in swift. You can also build your own chat UI if you prefer, it is just a sample

Comment: @abdulajet, i found a text chat sample in swift https://github.com/sbuxar/TokBox-Text-Chat-in-swift but it is not working, can u have a look at it once.